# C#: change button name and click function name

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am starting with C# programming, I have a scenario, where I create a windows form application. I have created a button inside the form and double click it to generate its associated click function. The visual studio generates the function with default name.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Now when I rename the button in properties, the function name remains same, making it difficult to relate button and function, I have an old code where a lot of such cases are present. So, I cannot delete and recreate the buttons and other things.

How can I rename the functions when I rename the button?

Comment: Have you tryed clicking in the function name and pressing f2 ;)

Comment: `private void yournewbuttonname_Click(object sender, EvenArgs e)`
manually change it to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the name of the method by simply typing the new name in place of the old one when editing the code.  Just like changing any text.

Then you can validate that the control still uses that event by either:

1. Go to the Form designer and select the control.  Check its properties/events and make sure the name still lines up.
2. Go to the code *generated by* the form designer and find where it assigns the method to the event, and change it if it needs to be changed.

Either one of these *should* also update the other one automatically, though I imagine it's generally preferred to use the first approach for consistency with the rest of the form design process.

Note that the method name can be anything you like, there's no steadfast rule that says it *must* be `controlName_eventName(object sender, EvenArgs e)`.  For example, if you have multiple controls which share an event handler then you don't have to decide which control gets to be the one in the method name.  You can give it any common name, such as `saveFormChanges(object sender, EvenArgs e)` and still assign it as the handler for that event.

Answer (score 9):

Right click on the function name and select Rename.  The name will be highlighted (it's green on my system, see picture below).  Edit the name and then hit the Apply button.  The button's click event will correctly point to the newly renamed method.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the name of Event from the property window.[image]

Answer (score 2):

go to your designer Right Click -> Properties (F4) -> Events -> ClickEvent -> Type in the name what so ever you want and click this will create Click event with the name you entered

Answer (score 2):

change `button1_Click` method name in code to new name and then press ctrl+. (period) and chose Rename. Alternatively, click on light bulb and select Rename.

Answer (score 1):

Name of the function does not necessary need to match button name, it's just the convention which makes it easier to understand which element is bound to which function on which event.

If you enter the `FormName.Designer.cs` file, you will find `InitializeComponent` function which contains the properties setup of all form elements, including their event binding. For example, you will probably have something like this over there:

```
this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
```

where `button1` is name of the element, `Click` is name of the event of that element and `button1_Click` is the name of the function handling that event.

If you're in the design mode of the form `FormName.cs [Design]` you can find the lightning icon inside the VisualStudio `Properties` window (one of the tabs next to your `Solution Explorer` tab). Under that icon, you will find the list of all the possible events of the currently selected element in your designer. On the example of your button it should look like this:

[image]

You can handle the event binding either here or inside your `FormName.Designer.cs` file, but it's preferable through this view because content of the `Designer` file is automatically generated. `InitializeComponent` function is then called inside the constructor of your form which initializes the form based on the setup of your designer file.